# Cancel a comment upvote

Tags: discussion, comments, up-votes

This has been bothered my for a while. And a [related discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment) is in metaSE, while the post is tagged with [status-declined] and the community seems to disagree with it.

Sometimes by accident I up-voted a wrong comment. Sometimes I misread the comment, and I want to undo my decision. (My fault, of course!) Sometimes I just want to flag the comment instead of upvoting, but after the upvote we *can't even* flag the comment!
That really makes me hesitate to use the functionality of upvoting and flagging. If we can cancel an upvote in a reasonable amount of time (just like the upvotes for questions and answers), it would represents the community's opinion much better.

> Should we have the ability to cancel a comment upvote?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Update*: Since April 2012, we can cancel a comment upvote by clicking the upward arrow again.  We can cancel a comment upvote only for 60 seconds and only if we have not navigated to another page.  [Read this for more detail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment/129032#129032).

---

Yes, we should.  As you wrote very appropriately, there are several reasons why canceling comment upvotes for a limited time window will be useful.  However, note that they declined the request (in August 2009) on Meta Stack Exchange and have not reversed the decision even with more than 70 upvotes.  I would not hold my breath.